# I have to create random number dice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a dice with the number as shown `{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}`
but I'm getting the output of `{2, 3, 4, 5}`. Also consider `kodiya = dice`.
I have mapped the outcomes to the respective sprites.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

    {
            Ray touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(touchPosition, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    if (coroutineAllowed)
                        StartCoroutine("RollKodiya");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private IEnumerator RollKodiya()
{
    coroutineAllowed = false;
    int randomKodiya = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 };
        int index = Random.Range(0, numbers.Length -1);
        randomKodiya = numbers[index];
        rend.sprite = kodiya[randomKodiya];
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
    gameControl.kodiyaThrown = randomKodiya + 1;
    gameControl.MovePlayer(1);
    coroutineAllowed = true;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and paste your code here instead of linking to images.

Comment: Also include all relevant code ... there is nothing wrong in how you get the random number ...  `randomKodiya` should always have values from `{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}` ... you are adding `+1` though .. so that might explain why you get `{2, 3, 4, 5, 9}` instead .. and for the `9` it probably fails with an exception at `kodiya[randomKodiya]`

Comment: @derHugo you are saying 9 fail with an exception at kodiya[randomKodiya] so is there any way to assign the sprites kodiya the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 8} if i have 5 sprites and each sprite when clicked should contain the above values so as to move my character that number of steps. Also I have edited the code and removed the number + 1 from randomKodiya, and now if i have the sprite to which I have assigned the value 2 is only moving one less step i.e 1 number of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all note that the second `int` index of `Random.Range` is **exclusive** so it should be

```
int index = Random.Range(0, numbers.Length);
```

which now returns numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 8`. Before you only could return values `1, 2, 3, 4` because you skipped the last.

---

**However**, from your comments it sounds like you are using the indices wrong anyway!

You say you have **5** sprites in your `kodiya` list/array so the only allowed indices are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

So using the random index from the `1,2,3,4,8` for accessing the 5 existing elements of `kodiya` makes no sense!

So there you probably would rather go

```
randomKodiya = numbers[index];
rend.sprite = kodiya[index];
```

---

In general instead of three parallel individual arrays I personally would rather use a proper setup data structure like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class DiceResult
{
    public int value;
    public Sprite sprite;
}
```

and configure in your Inspector that single array

```
// Fill in the values and reference the sprite in each element accordingly
public DiceResult[] _diceResults = new _diceResults[5];
```

and then use

```
var index = Random.Range(0, _diceResults.Length);
var result = _diceResults[index];
randomKodiya = result.value;
rend.sprite = result.sprite;
```